# Storing session data in cookies

Tags: php, session, cookies

Lately I have stumbled upon some articles that suggest using a cookie to store session data.
I liked the idea and extended my session storage by adding a CookieStorage class which works fine (note that per user I use a unique hash key for sigining and encrypting data)
However, there are a lot of other articles that suggest against storing sensitive data in a cookie, even though you encrypt and sign the value.

Personally, I find no reason why not do it especially when encrypting and signing the value with a different key for each user. The risk of the data being compromised is the same as with normal sessions, no? Not to mention that if you use SSL then the risk for hijacking is eleiminated.

What I see as a benefit with such an approach, if the session data are not large, is fewer IO operations on the server for opening/reading/writing session data, whether the storage is file, db, memory based

I would appreciate your feedback on the matter

Thanks

Comment: The benefit that you see in reducing I/O is most likely not that big to begin with (especially as deceze already said, when you use memcached or something) – but you are buying it with more data to send with _each_ HTTP request, which will make surfing your site slower for the user. (You can limit cookies to a certain path, ok – but if you want to use them on every page of your project, that path will most likely be just `/`)

Comment: It is true that the response will be larger, but that depends on the session data as well. If your sessions are small, you will not have a problem. On the other hand, if you have a really busy site, you save a lot of I/O just by using a cookie as storage for your sessions.

Comment: Not only the response will be larger, the requests as well. And without additional measures the cookies will be send in requests for static ressource like JS, CSS, images as well, even though they are not the least interested in session data (yes, that could be overcome by putting those on another subdomain). For your “really busy” site the aforementioned memcache or similar to store the session data will reduce/eliminate physical I/o operations. Whereas the encrypted data in cookies will mean more CPU consumption for decryption.

Comment: And _since_ the data is to be encrypted, it will not be used client-side ever. So sending it back and forth between client and server does not make much sense really. Conclusion: Apart from under _very special_ circumstances, this is still not a good idea IMHO.

Comment: Sure, memcached/redis are excellent options, but still I/O. Assuming you also use the above for caching and a page hits the cache let's say 5 times to fetch data and you need 2 operations for each request just for sessions, it may worth the CPU cycles, assuming a really high traffic site. As for the data being encrypted and not usable client side I do not see the downside. Do you use all of your cookies client side? I rarely do

Comment: _“Do you use all of your cookies client side? I rarely do”_ – my point is, what’s the use of sending session data to and from the client each time, if the client does not even need that data? IMHO you are just introducing new attack vectors (should your encryption get cracked), and the so-called benefits don’t convince me.

Comment: Actually, I am not trying to convince anyone. I started the thread in order to get some feedback and have different opinions be heard,  nothing more. Someone else may find all of these different views interesting

Comment: Me neither :-) I’m just giving my opinion, and I think the proposed benefits are smaller than the drawbacks – but in the end it’s everybody’s own decision what they do and how they implement something.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using *pure cookie storage* with no server-side component at all, then the user is in control of the data. The only thing keeping him from it is your encryption/signing method; but that can be attacked. If you're not using encryption/signing keys specific to the user's session (i.e. you're not using a server-side session), then you're pretty much limited to a static secret. Someone could attack that offline, trying to brute force it. Once they did, they could spoof their entire session.

If you are using more secure one-time random secrets stored in a server-side session... you're already storing data in a server-side session! Why not keep it simple and store everything there? It would also reduce the bandwidth needs required to transfer all the cookies back and forth with every single request.

If you're doing this mainly to save I/O operations on the server: use a more efficient session store like a memcache based store.

Comment: Not to mention replay attacks. The attacker does not need to know the meaning of the crypted cookie, but must simply know that string and send it back. If the server has no means of knowing if this is an active session, the cookie still is valid.

Comment: @deceze, thanks for the input. All valid points. The thing is, how possible would be to successfully brute force a strong encryption. Then, the same applies to normal session ids. Someone could try to guess a valid session id identifier and hijack the session.

Comment: @Sven, The cookie has information of the user's last activity time. After 20 minutes of inactivity, the cookie is no longer valid. So replay attacks are not an issue, without a spoofed cookie

Comment: @Thomas That depends on how strong the encryption is exactly and how determined the attacker is. If you're using one static secret for everyone, that's extremely risky. If you're using randomly generated keys which are only valid for some time, the risk is significantly lower. Same principle as with limited validity of session ids.

Comment: An attacker has a better chance to break into the server than breaking data encrypted with strong cryptography. The biggest limitation in storing session data in the cookie is the size of the cookie.

Comment: @Sp. Another good point... if an attacker gets a hold of the secret in any way, he's free to spoof anyone's session forever, possibly unnoticed.

Comment: It all comes down to how secure are the encryption algorithms? Any input on this matter? I agree that it is more possible to break into the server, than breaking strong encryption

Comment: @Thomas I'd say it depends on whether you're rotating your secrets at all + the strength of the encryption used. State-of-the-art AES encryption with sufficiently long keys is probably as secure as can be, which reduces the problem to the rotation of keys. Which, again, comes down to the storage of keys on the server, which, again, IMO kinda makes the point of this whole exercise moot. ;)

Comment: I agree with you that introducing rotating keys requires some kind of persistence. My approach is alleviating such a need and depend on strong encryption. But in reality, have you ever heard of AES encryption being compromised?

Comment: @Thomas True, in reality this is probably not feasible. **But**, that then depends on you keeping the key secret. *Perfectly* secret. It just needs to leak once for the whole scheme to come crumbling down. There's no such risk at all with traditional sessions.

Comment: To leak the key, means the server has been compromised, which means the session is the least of my problems :)

Comment: @Thomas Yes and no. You need to secure the entire process of handling the secret. From typing it into your workstation to transferring it to the server to storing it on the server to managing access rights of employees to anywhere they could see the secret. It only needs to get into the wrong hands *once*, *anywhere*.  "Secret" really *means* **secret** here.

Comment: I don't think the replay issue has been sorted out. First point: There is a window of opportunity for at least 20 minutes. Second: If only the cookie contains the entire session state, grabbing a cookie once, duplicate it and continue the session from there on with a different browser is possible. And a completely different issue: What if two concurrent requests with the same initial cookie data are being worked on, and both change two different session variables inside the crypt string? You cannot merge the two changes into one new cookie.

Answer (score 0):

1. Although nowadays session id transferred only via cookies, initially there was other ways, which are still supported and can be used.
2. Sometimes server needs to know or alter the session info.
3. That point from @CBroe on the cookie size.

Comment: What do you mean by 2? The server will be able to alter the data just fine. The idea here is to use a cookie as the persistence medium, instead of let's say, the filesystem or a db or memcached or redis or anything