# Cookies in PHP when i change password

Tags: php, cookies

I am using Cookies for website, which is working fine for me . I am not using Session for my website . Problem is that

**I am logged in from one computer.  And i made login in another computer or browser from same account.**

**And i changed the password from my second computer  but it keeps logging me from my first computer.**

Is there is any way to stop logging from my first computer, if i made chnage in password from second computer.

I am storing this information

```
$expire=time()+3600*24*30;
$useraccesstoken=$_POST['user_access_token'];
$userid=$_POST['user_id'];
setcookie("user_access_token", $useraccesstoken, $expire);
setcookie("user_id", $userid, $expire);
```

And for logout i am using

this

```
$expire=time()-3600*24*30;
setcookie("user_access_token","", $expire);
setcookie("user_id","", $expire);
```

Thanks

Comment: Please tell me you're not storing login credentials in a cookie. Please.

Comment: @Kamalpreet than how are you checking that user is logged in or not.?

Comment: if user_id is there or not

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are not using a right method for login process you should use session because of two reason

1. Cookies are stored in browser
2. While session is stored in server so that no one can change the session data.

Lets take a case scenerio that you have two type of login one for a use and another for admin that normal user can make a change in cookie and easily become a admin.
You should store only thoose value in cookie that are not used in security like time of last login last viewed items or something like that

Now coming to your problem You have stored some cookie in first computer for a long time may be for 1 day and you have changed the password on other computer but cookie in first computer already exists thats why you are being logged in.
You have to destroy the cookie first that you will not be able to login without new password.

**Important** NEVER EVER STORE LOGIN CREDENTIALS OR ANY SECERET INFORMATION IN COOKIE

you should also see 
[storing-session-data-in-cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527479/storing-session-data-in-cookies)

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you store in a cookie.

Let's say when I login, you create a cookie which has my username in it. There is no sessions control so everything depends on this cookie. So as long as I have cookie, I don't care about password changes.

Let's say you store username and password in a cookie. I guess you don't. If you do store both and still login after a password change, there must be an error with your code.

If you're not storing password too, I guess you can control this by comparing cookie create date to password change date. If cookie creation date

Long story short, don't use cookies for this kind of things.